# Efficient way needed

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

Given N, M find the :

GCD(1, 1) * GCD(1, 2) * … * GCD(1, M) * GCD(2, 1) * GCD(2, 2) * … * GCD(2, M) * … * GCD(N, 1) * GCD(N, 2) * … * GCD(N, M) modulo 10^9+7

Constraints:

1 <= N, M <= 2 * 10^7

Tried using brute force but need a help to improve.

Comment: if I understand your problem correctly you will be doing $20000000^2=
400000000000000$ multiplications, gcd's and mods. That is a really big number. Possibly one of the intermediate calculations will be 0, then the entire calculation would be 0.

Comment: yes. that's why i am asking for any better and efficient way